# Configuration setup through bashrc source command

Tags: bash

I am sourcing a library in the following manner

```
source "${envirs_trkrc}/envirs.rc"
source "${linge_trkrc}/licars.rc"
source "${linge_trkrc}/curiplaya.rc"

source "${linge_trkrc}/cellar.rc"
source "${edvart_trkrc}/marinex.rc"
source "${edvart_trkrc}/firefly.rc"
source "${edvart_trkrc}/navaid.rc"
source "${baikonur_trkrc}/buranex.rc"
source "${gunars_trkrc}/comseq.rc"
source "${gunars_trkrc}/comint.rc"
```

I would like a basic setup that only activates the first three tools

```
source "${envirs_trkrc}/envirs.rc"
source "${linge_trkrc}/licars.rc"
source "${linge_trkrc}/curiplaya.rc"
```

and exclude the rest. What kind of option could one do to activate the basic setup or the full one?

Have done

```
basic=true
if [[ basic ]]; then
  source "${envirs_trkrc}/envirs.rc"
  source "${linge_trkrc}/licars.rc"
  source "${linge_trkrc}/curiplaya.rc"
else
  source "${linge_trkrc}/cellar.rc"
  source "${edvart_trkrc}/marinex.rc"
  source "${edvart_trkrc}/firefly.rc"
  source "${edvart_trkrc}/navaid.rc"
  source "${baikonur_trkrc}/buranex.rc"
  source "${gunars_trkrc}/comseq.rc"
  source "${gunars_trkrc}/comint.rc"
fi
```

But the above is not correct because I want the user to either supply `--basic`, otherwise does everything.  By default I want the full library installation, and only if the user supplies `--basic` would the basic setup be applied.

Comment: Please edit your question (no comment): What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Comment: Do you know about `if / then / else` logic? Good luck.

Comment: Is this actually in your .bashrc, as the title implies? Because .bashrc runs automatically for each new (interactive, non-login) bash shell, so it should not require any interaction and doesn't have an opportunity for the user to choose what mode to run in.

Comment: It would be good to have a switch that a user can use so that when they run a terminal window again, only the basic setup is executed.  This would help should there be some errors in situations when a user makes changes to the code, or extends the library with their own tools.

Comment: currently I have a function that users can call from their `.bashrc` called `kamchatka-utils-launch`.  So one can do `kamchatka-utils-launch --basic` instead.

Comment: I do not understand the problem. So _you_ have to implement that functionality if you want to have it.  If you want to have `--basic` option then parse and implement the logic. `What kind of option could one do to activate` "One" could do "any" kind of option one wants to have. I do not understand the question. It is too broad. You can have any infinite number of options, or none, it's up to you. `But the above is not correct because I want the user` So instead, just write code that will do that, not the above code. (Also, `[[ basic ]]` will be _always_ true.)

Comment: Have done `if [[ "$basic" == false ]]; then source "${linge_trkrc}/cellar.rc" ... fi`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test whether a user supplies a command line argument, you need to test if a user supplies a command line argument. It is as simple as that.

So, that would be, in its most simple form:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$1" = "--basic" ] ; then
    # Include the basic libraries
else
    # include all libraries, including also the basic ones
fi
```

Note that this is a very rudimentary way of checking command line arguments. In real life, you would check `$#` (the number of arguments) and you would probably use `getopts`.